# colocar nombre de usuario aun lado de bienvenido

Tags: php, html5

Hola amigos como puedo poner el nombre del usuario aun lado de la palabra **Bienvenido**, por medio de `php`.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 class="text-titles">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-circle zmdi-hc-fw"></i>Bienvenido <?php. $_SESSION['usuario'];?></small>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <p class="lead">Esté es un foro web que se realizó con fines educativos!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que una solución sería `<?php echo $_SESSION['usuario'];?>`, pero sin mas contexto, no sé si podríamos decirte.

Comment: no estás haciendo echo, así que PHP no va a incrustar nada en el HTML

Comment: perdon, puse echo antes del $_SESSION pero aun asi no funciona

Answer (score 1):

Con el punto (.) concatenas variables y texto en `PHP`, pero no es tu caso. En su lugar puedes usar cualquiera de los siguientes métodos que son equivalentes:

```
Bienvenido <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario'];?>
Bienvenido <?= $_SESSION['usuario'];?>
```

El archivo debe tener extensión **.php** y no puede ser **.html**.

Si no funciona, asegúrate que la variable de sesión existe. Puedes usar `print_r($_SESSION);` para validar que exista.

Por otro lado, estás cerrando esta etiqueta `</small>` pero no veo la de apertura.